# Programmatically acquire access_token from ADFS 3.0 with OAuth2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, adfs3.0

I have implemented an OAuth2 provider in ADFS 2012R2 that is being consumed in both a Xamarin application with a NodeJS server. I want to write automated tests against my NodeJS Rest Endpoints so I need to generate an access_token programmatically from ADFS. I have searched far and wide and can't seem to figure out how to get an access_token from ADFS 3.0 programmatically (2016 and above have more supported grant types that allow it). Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

I have tried this solution here: [Does ADFS 2012 R2 support Auth2 Resource Owner Password Credentials flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869778/does-adfs-2012-r2-support-auth2-resource-owner-password-credentials-flow) with the endpoint of "https://myadfsserver/adfs/oauth2/token" with 
a grant_type=password, but that doesn't work as ADFS 2012R2 doesn't support that grant_type.

I have tried ADAL:

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorizeUrl, false);
            AuthenticationResult result;
            try
            {
                  result = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(Resource, ClientId, new UserPasswordCredential("username", "password"));
            }
```

but that fails with 3 different exceptions at once.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 3.0 only supports web API as per [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).

As you say, it doesn't support all flows.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.